# How to authenticate JWT via websocket?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, jwt

I have a REST API server written in Node js, and a websocket server that get as a parameter my HTTP server.

I want to establish a connection with the user only after authentication (using JWT).
This is my verifyToken func:

```
verifyToken: (req, res, next) => 
    {
        const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
        const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
        if (token == null)
        {
            return res.send("No token sent");
        } 
      
        jwt.verify(token, publicToken, (err, payload) => 
        {
          if(err) 
          {
              return res.send("Not valid token");
          }
          
          req.payload = payload
          next()
        })
      }
```

I want to use this authentication in here:

```
wss.on('connection', (ws) =>
{
 **verify token**
console.log('A new user connected');
}
```

How can I do it?